# Horizontally Center align bootstrap 4 form in a row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I design a simple bootstrap form in an md-col-8 column to prevent it from going full width.

In aligning the form horizontally i have tried all kinds of bootstrap 4 classes like "text-center", "justify-content-center", "mx-auto" but non works

Submit

I what the form to horizontally align at the center but it stays left aligned.

Answer (score 1):

first, change the class name its "col-md-8" not "md-col-8" and you can do the div center with "justify-content-md-center" or "justify-content-center" class if you add this in "row" class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the block to align as a whole, you can add the `offset-md-2` class so the column is offset 2 blocks, that would center the block.

Comment: i have tried offset i did not work, can you see my code

Comment: I can, in fact, not see your code.

Comment: thanks col-md-offset-2 worked for me